# How to swap the 1st and the last string of 2d array without using ANY loops?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to swap 1st and last rows of 2d array without using any loops. How to do that?

For example let`s take a String array:

```
a11 a12 a13 |
a21 a22 a23 |
a31 a32 a33 |
```

Output:

```
a31 a32 a33 |
a21 a22 a23 |
a11 a12 a13 |
```

Comment: what is the expected output and what is it that you are getting?

Comment: Also where is the 2d array ?

Comment: That would be `String[] t = array[2]; array[2] = array[0]; array[0] = t;`.

Comment: with *first* and *last* you mean *the first element of the first array of the 2d array* and *the last element of the last array of the 2d array* or just *the first array of the 2s array* and *the last array of the 2d array*? It's a 2d array: you need to be specific. Ok, I'll put it simply: do you mean `A[0]` or `A[0][0]` ?

Comment: A[0][0]. I need to replace 1st ROW with LAST ROW and vice-versa

Comment: @Sterconium, according to his example he means "strings" for "rows" (so I believe upvoted comment is correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] tmp = A[0];
A[0] = A[A.length-1];
A[A.length-1] = tmp;
```

It'll work with any size of arrays.

Comment: I need to move whole row